# Como fazer um loop que compara string com um float em python?

Tags: python

Estou atribuindo o valor `1.5` a variável `h`, porém ela não aceita valores do tipo `float` e não finaliza o código.

```py
h = (input("Informe sua altura: ")) # aqui ele recebe um elemento qualquer

while h != float:  # aqui faz a comparação(se fosse float deveria proceder)
    h = (input("Informe sua altura: "))  

    if h == float:
        print(h)
```

Answer (score 6):

Simples tentativa de tentar tranformar em float (com isto tu consegues saber se a string digitada tem o formato igual ao de um float):

```
h = input("Informe sua altura: ")
try:
    float(h)
    print('É float, altura: ' ,h)
except ValueError as err:
    print('Não é float')
```

Com repetição do `input`, sem função:

```
while True:
    h = input("Informe sua altura: ")
    try:
        float(h)
        break
    except ValueError as err:
        print('formato errado')
print('altura:', h)
```

Com repetição do `input`, com função recursiva:

```
def return_float():
    h = input("Informe sua altura: ")
    try: 
        return float(h)
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Formato errado, por favor tente outravez')
    return return_float()
print('a sua altura é', return_float())
```

Por fim para seguir a lógica do teu e pelo que me pediste em comentário, "...não posso usar nem o try nem o except...", podes fazer assim:

```
while True:
    h = input("Informe sua altura: ")
    if h.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        break
    print('formato errado')
print('altura:', float(h))
```

Comment: Não seria mais interessante, ao invés de `float(h)` e depois `return h`, fazer tudo na mesma linha? `return float(h)`?

Comment: Sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez, isso de facto reduz uma linha. Obgado

Comment: obrigado  Miguel , porem eu queria entender oque tem de errado nesta expressão    while h != float :              eu não queria usar def para isto , poxa eu só quero que ele compare e veja se é float ou não

Comment: Mas precisa de repetir o input caso não seja certo @AdrianoSouza?

Comment: sim miguel infelizmente precisa

Comment: Valeu ae miguel, mas eu não posso usar nem o try nem o except, só comandos de decisão if e else e loop for and while, por enquanto eu vou fazer ele de maneira usando a função range com uma altura que vai de 1.2 ate 500

Comment: Sim miguel mas quando eu digito 1.4 ele também não reconhece como float

Comment: Só para complementar a resposta, pois considero a mais completa:
`h = (input("Informe sua altura: "))`. estes parênteses são desnecessários pode ser escrito `h = input("Informe sua altura: ")`.

Comment: Ha claro obgado @fernandosavio , bem visto acho que estava a colocar a função float antes e esqueci-me de tirar. Obgado

Answer (score 3):

Falta a conversão explícita para `float`:

```
h = float(input("Informe sua altura: "))
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

Comment: sim mas se eu faço a conversão explicita ele me da o erro...                                           que se eu colocar qualquer valor string  ele não e um valor float tipo digitar meu nome ele retorna erro por isto não coloquei como float

Comment: Qual erro? Pode editar sua pergunta com ele?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'dt'      por exemplo se eu digitar uma string

Comment: Ah, você quer tratar qualquer coisa que for lida. Para este caso, [a resposta do @Miguel resolve isso com perfeição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140451/2999).